# Streaming output from Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Popen output always arrives as a byte array at once after the process finished, I tried several configurations including using a file for stdout.

To create a progress bar, I would like to receive the output one by one. In this example only one `p.stdout.read()` returns all the `1`'s as a byte array.

[Example in Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dp4wIfiEZSxmpDOIsfHhsX1cOy31UfNT#scrollTo=9_hgJCsn-CiL)

```python
# shell.py
import sys, time

for _ in range(5):
    print(1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

---

```python
# code.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', 'shell.py'],
        stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False, bufsize=1)

output = p.stdout.read()
while output:
    print('output:', output)
    output = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Would love to know how this could work.  I have also tried sending stdout for the same purpose to a file and then just `cat`ing the file to see what would would happen.  It appears that stdout is not streamed to the file, but only dumped at the end when the process is completed, and passing a BytesIO or StringIO object seems to give an error

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how many bytes read() will read. if you use p.stdout.read(1) in code.py, your code will work as you want. Note that python's print function adds newlines to the output of shell.py, so code.py will print this out:

```
output: b'1'
output: b'\n'
output: b'1'
output: b'\n'
output: b'1'
output: b'\n'
```

Also worth mentioning is that this will read *bytes*. If you want, say, unicode characters one by one, you'll have to do some processing yourself.